# Laravel: set session cookie with different flags depending on route

Tags: laravel, session, cookies, laravel-8

So Im well aware i can change my session.php settings to allow for a session to be implemented inside an iframe.  Unfortunately for me whenever I do, when i try to log in i get a 419 and the session stuff doesnt work OUTSIDE of the iframe.

I need to somehow set the following values for the session ONLY for certain routes (which will be inside and stay inside an iframe).  I can't for the life of me find a good way to do this.

```
'secure' => true,
'same_site' => "none",
```

EDIT: So I somewhat resolved this with some middleware but the problem is now that cookies that are set in the iframe under https cannot be used or overwritten if you go to http.  In production it works like a champ though.  If anyone has any suggestions on how to manage the secure vs non secure cookies feel free.  Ill post the solution I have below.

Answer (score -1):

So in case anyone needs to do this in the future here is the middleware needed to do this.  It needs to be added to the $middleware variable in the http kernel.  The one issue is when testing if you are crossing http and https you will need to manually delete cookies for http if they were set using https.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

class AllowIframeSession
{
    private $allowedPaths;

    function __construct(){
        $this->allowedPaths = [
            'forms/public',
            'landing/',
        ];
    }
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @param \Closure $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
    {
        foreach($this->allowedPaths as $path)
        {
            if (substr($request->path(), 0, strlen($path)) === $path)
            {
                // Allow sessions in iframes on other domains
                config(['session.secure' => true]);
                config(['session.same_site' => "none"]);
            }

        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```